# convert a visual studio app to work for android os

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I Have developed an  application/software using MS-Access database in Visual Studio 2010. How can I convert it or make it run on Android os?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to "convert it".  There is no comparable functionality for Access in Android.  Your closest match would be SQL-Lite.

Your best bet, if you want to use existing libraries, is to use [Mono for Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid).

This should allow you to use your C# code in the Android framework.

Comment: Hey Pheonixblade9 : I tried what u were trying to say...Will Xamarin not help me use my previously built application's code to share and reuse that code in an Android Platform.?? Plzzz help

Comment: I am not familiar with Xamarin, but any "migration tools" are always to be used carefully.  You're better off rewriting the code in most cases.

Comment: In Mono for Android will I be able to use a Data Source as Access Database as I did in Visual Studio?? If I change my database to some other then I will have to change a lot of my code....Actually i m building for an android tablet.

Comment: You will have to change a lot of your code.  There's no way around it.  Access is completely different from SQLite.  You might be able to use it as a data source, but I highly doubt it.